# Combine strings for output in HTML

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Which is the right way to combine strings for output ?

```
%%[
SET @BankName = "American Express through"
SET @ThankYouFrom1 = "%%=v(@BankName)=%% c/o AnyBank Corp"
SET @ThankYouFrom2 = Concat(@BankName, " c/o ", "AnyBank Corp")
]%%
%%=v(@ThankYouFrom1)=%%
%%=v(@ThankYouFrom2)=%%
```

I can't seem to get ouput shown at ampscript.io

Comment: Please make sure to share relevant context and use tags to draw attention from expert community members. I've tagged this question `marketing-cloud` and `ampscript`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ampscript.io](https://ampscript.io) never shows any output, just possible syntax issues.

The [Concat](https://ampscript.guide/concat/) function you have used in the second example is the best option for combining multiple strings.

For the first example to work, you’d have to wrap the output in a [TreatAsContent](https://ampscript.guide/treatascontent/) function:

```
%%[
SET @BankName = "American Express through"
SET @ThankYouFrom1 = "%%=v(@BankName)=%% c/o AnyBank Corp"
SET @ThankYouFrom2 = Concat(@BankName, " c/o ", "AnyBank Corp")
]%%
%%=treatascontent(@ThankYouFrom1)=%%
%%=v(@ThankYouFrom2)=%%
```

Comment: What would you know about how ampscript.io works? ….oh, wait… 

Comment: I might know a thing or two ;-)

Comment: haha... who else can better know about `ampscript.io` than the Author herself :)